# C# deserialization a Json response

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON:

```
{
    "related": [
        {
            "titulo": "pt cruiser models"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "pt 19"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "isel pt"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "ewee pt"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "camera pt"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "pt 24 7"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "ryan pt 22"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "taurus pt 24 7"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "stearman pt 17"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "pt 17 stearman"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "star wars pt"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "temperature sensor pt 100"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "pt 100 temperature sensor"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "ejot delta pt"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "delta pt screws"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "chrysler pt cruiser cabriolet"
        },
        {
            "titulo": "ryan pt 22 for sale"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the following clases:

```
class Related
{
    private Titulos _related;

    public Titulos related
    {
        set { _related = value; }
        get { return _related; }
    }
}

class Titulos
{

    private string _titulo;
    public string titulo
    {
        set
        {
            _titulos.Add(value);
            _titulo = value;
        }
        get { return _titulo; }
    }

    private List<string> _titulos = new List<string>();
    public List<string> titulos
    {
        set
        {
            _titulos = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _titulos;
        }
    }
}
```

For deserializing the json from the response:

```
response_related_search = readStream.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(response_related_search);
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Related>(response_related_search);
```

The error is:

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List&lt;T&gt; that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path 'related', line 1, position 12.

I'm a little lost in this situation and can not figure out who to fix it.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: There a lot online utils which will generate class for you based on the given json. For example [https://jsonutils.com/](https://jsonutils.com/)

Comment: Thanks @Fabio for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `titulos` property in the JSON, which means your data model in C# does not reflect the data you're trying to deserialize.

Looks like your classes should be:

```
class Related
{
    public List<Titulos> related { get; set; }
}

class Titulos
{
    public string titulo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As addition to the answer if OP want keep names of the properties to follow .Net conventions: he can use [JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) for separating json names and .net property names

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same naming convention like you have in the json object, json always return in camelcase. 
secondly, your code is having private variables and also have some extra things. try the following code.

```
class Related
{

    public Titulos[] related { get; set; }


}

class Titulos
{

    public string titulo { get; set; }


}
```

and implement the above code for result as.

```
          string jsonObject = @"{
                    'related': [
                        {
                            'titulo': 'pt cruiser models'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'pt 19'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'isel pt'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'ewee pt'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'camera pt'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'pt 24 7'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'ryan pt 22'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'taurus pt 24 7'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'stearman pt 17'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'pt 17 stearman'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'star wars pt'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'temperature sensor pt 100'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'pt 100 temperature sensor'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'ejot delta pt'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'delta pt screws'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'chrysler pt cruiser cabriolet'
                        },
                        {
                            'titulo': 'ryan pt 22 for sale'
                        }
                    ]
                }";


        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Related>(jsonObject);
```

place a break point after result and you have all the objects. enjoy...